# How do i find all backups of an azure sql database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have an azure sql database. I have initiated backups. But if I go to restore I want to pick which restore I want. I would have expected to find a list of backups like the following:

```
        Fullbackup <date>
        Sequential <date>   
        Sequential <date>
        Sequential <date>
        Fullbackup <date>   etc
```

and I would be able to pick which backup I want to restore.
I have tried loooking for them but cant seem to get any.

How can i get a list of backups ?
Also why does it restore to the same resourcegroup , can i change that ?
Can i also restore to a different sql server ?

UPDATE:

```
I was after a list of backups , so for example something like
```

Backup time          Backup expiration time (UTC)

2021-02-10 23:19     2021-04-21 23:19
2021-02-17 04:00     2021-02-28 04:00

How can i configure the backup policies to get this ?
So if i need to restore i have an option to pick which restore i want .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following PowerShell cmdlet to get a list of all restore points:

```
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseRestorePoints -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName
```

The result of the previous cmdlet may be similar to the following:

```
ResourceGroupName        : resourcegroup01
ServerName               : server01
DatabaseName             : database01
Location                 : Central US
RestorePointType         : CONTINUOUS
RestorePointCreationDate : 
EarliestRestoreDate      : 1/18/2024 12:00:00 AM
RestorePointLabel        : RestorePoint01
```

You can restore to another resource group, and any logical server, on the same region and, if you use [geo-redundant backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?view=azuresql#backup-storage-redundancy), you can restore to other regions as well.

Comment: how can i use az cli cmds not Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseRestorePoints ?

Comment: Based on the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest) you can use AZ CLI to restore a backup (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-db-restore) but at this moment you cannot use AZ to list all restore points.

Comment: right ... so doesnt azure keep like lets say 4 full backups and transaction etc ?

Comment: It is one full backup a week, diff backups every 12 hours and tlog backups every 10 minutes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?view=azuresql#backup-frequency

Comment: I have seen this doco, my question is there will be 1 full backup each week and what about sequential/differential , if i have said keep for 4 weeks , would there be a list that i can select from to restore. Also can i copy these bakcups as .bacpac files and store on an external drive ?

Comment: If you use the portal or the cmdlet I provided in my answer you will have a list of restore porints available. Automated backups arre not available to you as files and you cannot alter their retention above 35 days. What you can do is to schedule an export as bacpac of your databases to Azure Blob Storage, and there you can retain those bacapac (backup files) for years.